# Error while doing assessment using Data migration assistant (DMA) tool

Tags: azure-sql-database, database-migration, azure-migrate, sqlmigrations

Getting error while doing assessment using DMA tool for choosing **assessment type as Integration Services**.

**Error message :**

The assessment of database 'Package store' on server 'STP637388' failed.

The error message: 'Failed to assess SSIS packages or projects: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'.'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move your existing SSIS packages and projects to Azure and use them with Azure SQL and Azure Managed Instance you need to read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-lift-shift-ssis-packages-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) documentation.

To assess SQL Server Integration Service(SSIS) packages, below components need to be installed with Data Migration Assistant:

- SQL Server Integration Service with the same version as the SSIS
  packages to assess.
- Azure Feature Pack or other third party components if SSIS packages to assess have these components.

DMA needs to run with administrator access to assess SSIS packages in Package Store.

Please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-assess-ssis?view=sql-server-ver15) documentation for more information.